# Power consumptions of the following 2 LED driving circuits

Tags: led, pulse, led-driver

I have simulated the following two circuits that can drive and pulse the LEDs.The transient result is shown on the right.

[image]

The thing I am not sure is that which circuit consumes more power? My idea is circuit 1 (left) because the current flowing through the top transistor never goes to zero. Am I right?

Btw, can anyone explain why some spikes occur in current lled2? Is it because of the charge injection?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have two methods. Method 1 diverts the current away from the LED but, the constant current is always flowing thus, you have more power taken from the supply.

Method 2 interrupts the current to the LED and this means the average current taken from the supply is smaller hence it is more efficient.

The spiking problem is caused by the constant current circuit going into overload when you disconnect the LED. The op-amp tries to keep the current flowing but it can't so it switches on the MOSFET (T4) as hard as it can (to no avail). When the disconnecting MOSFET reconnects the LED there is a current pulse because the op-amp has to stop driving T4 from being fully on and return to constant current mode.

Maybe try a different approach where you actually modulate the constant current generator. The input connected to the 2.5V battery shown on your circuit could be switched to Vcc - this then causes the op-amp to switch off the MOSFET T4. I think this would work better but the devil is always in the detail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do need a separate input for the opamp since I will vary the input voltage to achieve different current level.

Comment: You can use an analogue switch to divert the op-amp input from being connected to the control voltage. This is commonly done.

Comment: why are you suggesting to divert the op-amp input from connecting to the control voltage?

Comment: Because it keeps the opamp constant current circuit operating linearly and prevents the spike. In effect you modulate the control voltage instead of diverting or inhibiting the current into the led.